# Mysql event not running after database migration

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have recently upgraded my server and since then my event that calls a routine does not seem to be working correctly.

I know that the routine works becuase I can call it manually and it shows no errors.

The event code is shown below:

```
DROP EVENT `event_image_update_views`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `event_image_update_views` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2013-06-05 11:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO CALL image_update_views()
```

It basically asks the database to call a routine called image_update_views() every 5 minuets after a specific date.

Im fairly sure the date on my database is correct but im not 100% sure.  Is there a sql command that I can run that will return the current time/date, so that I know for certain that I am providing a future date?

I am also unsure about the line below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
```

Surely the root user should be used here right?

Is there any way in phpmyadmin to tell if the event has run or not?

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be that your the MySQL event scheduler is not running.

Try this to see if it is running:

```
show variables like 'event_scheduler';
```

If you get a value of `OFF` returned then this is probably the reason. You can switch it back on by running:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

If you need to know the MySQL current date and time you can run:

```
select now();
```

Finally, you can see when an event was last run by the MySQL Event Scheduler using this query:

```
select event_schema,event_name,last_executed 
from information_schema.events;
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**

If you need to switch your event_scheduler on by default then head over to your my.cnf file (or my.ini file if you are using Windows) and either comment out `event_scheduler=DISABLED` or set `event_scheduler=ON`. Then restart your MySQL server.

There is some more info about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-configuration.html).

Comment: Great answer! It turns out the event_scheduler is turned off by default. Switching it on solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Interestingly, I rebooted my server and it seems that event_scheduler gets reset to OFF. Is there a way of preventing this from happening?

Comment: yup. Head over to your my.cnf file (or my.ini file if you are using Windows) and either comment out the event_scheduler=DISABLED or set event_scheduler=ON. Then restart. There is some more info about it here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-configuration.html

Comment: Im on an ubuntu machine so it will be in the my.cnf file. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your comment about the option file setting to your answer