# MySQL event schedule not working

Tags: mysql

I have a event schedule in mySql which needs to run on 15th of every month at 2:00PM. i have written it as follows:

```
create event asdb.e_monthly
on schedule
every 1 month
starts '2013-07-15 13:59:59'
do
INSERT INTO asdb.abc_test values('monthly','monthly');
```

but its not inserting values to the abc_tes table. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Is the [`event_scheduler`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler) enabled?

Comment: Could be that your event scheduler is not switched on. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937280/mysql-event-not-running-after-database-migration/16937697#16937697

Comment: you can read this article http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/ only missing SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

Comment: Yes, event scheduler is already ON. i have run the command
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

But still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your event_scheduler is enable. By default, it is disabled.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

For more information check out following blog:

http://www.jeenalinfotech.com/blogs/mysql/mysql-event-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the `event_scheduler` is `ON` - execute the following command:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

It'll output a table/entries, you must look for an entry with User `event_schedule`r, and Command `Daemon`:

```
Id           User         Host      db  Command Time    State            Info
22870   event_scheduler localhost   \N   Daemon  23    Waiting for next activation  \N
```

**OR**, you can also verify using the following command:

```
SELECT @@global.event_scheduler;
```

The result should be `ON`, otherwise set it off (will get `0` for the command), as stated in the next section.

---

If you don't have any such entry (as above), you may start the event scheduler using the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Once done, you can verify if it has been executed properly using the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command, as mentioned above.